# How to rename key when moving after reading from S3 in Apache Camel?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, apache-camel

```java
String s3Url = "aws2-s3://mybucket?prefix=demo/notify/hello.txt" +
                "&useDefaultCredentialsProvider=true" +
                "&initialDelay=5000" +
                "&delay=60s" +
                "&moveAfterRead=true" +
                "&destinationBucket=mybucket" +
                "&destinationBucketPrefix=demo/archive" +
                "&maxMessagesPerPoll=1";

        log.info("start route for S3");
        from(s3Url)
                .routeId("S3 bucket route")
                .routeDescription("Read file from S3 bucket")
                .log("Headers : ${headers}")
                .log("Received body: ${body}")
        ;

        log.info("finish route for S3");
```

I am trying to read a file from S3 bucket `mybucket` with prefix `demo/notify/hello.txt` and move after reading to same bucket with prefix `demo/archive/hello.txt`

When I use the above code it moves it to the same bucket but with prefix `demo/archive/demo/notify/hello.txt`.

Is there a way to accomplish this using AWS S3 component of Apache Camel or otherwise?